# error ... ImportError: No module named cassandra.cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to follow the below video about write-paths and when i use the sample student-files that are provided i get below error....i am really new to cassandra and trying to figure out why the excerise file not work....i have provided the error that i get(ImportError: No module named cassandra.cluster) and also the .sh and .py file...any help is appriciated...

https://academy.datastax.com/courses/understanding-cassandra-write-path/understanding-data-files

```
    cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$ ccm list
 *demo_1node
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$ ccm status
Cluster: 'demo_1node'
---------------------
node1: UP
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$ ./write_data.sh 300000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./write_data.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ImportError: No module named cassandra.cluster
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$

cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$ cat write_data.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: write_data.sh <number of keys>"
  exit 0
fi

if [ `ccm status | grep "node1: UP" | wc -l` -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Cassandra cluster not up"
  exit 0
fi

./write_data.py $1
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$ cat write_data.py
#!/usr/bin/python

# This Python script will insert a number of keys into
# musicdb.user
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from random import randint
from sets import Set
from uuid import uuid4
import os,sys,time,binascii

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: python.py <number of keys>"
    sys.exit()

cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect()

insert_row_prepare = session.prepare("INSERT INTO musicdb.user (id,preferences) VALUES(?,?)")

quarter=int(int(sys.argv[1])/4)
half=int(int(sys.argv[1])/2)
three_quarter=int(int(sys.argv[1])/4)+int(int(sys.argv[1])/2)

for x in range(0,int(sys.argv[1])):
  id = uuid4()
  set = Set([binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),
             binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),
             binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),
             binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100)),binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(100))])
  insert_row_bind = insert_row_prepare.bind([id,set])
  session.execute(insert_row_bind)

  if (x+1) == int(sys.argv[1]):
    print "100% completed - " + str(x+1) + " rows inserted."
  elif (x+1) == quarter:
    print "25% completed - " + str(x+1) + " rows inserted."
  elif (x+1) == half:
    print "50% completed - " + str(x+1) + " rows inserted."
  elif (x+1) == three_quarter:
    print "75% completed - " + str(x+1) + " rows inserted."

time.sleep(1)
cluster.shutdown()
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$
```

Comment: Did you install the datastax python driver?

Comment: thank you richard, as i mentioned i am really new to this...but after installing the python drive it seems to work with a warning...

Comment: cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$ ./write_data.sh 3000
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqltypes.py:64: UserWarning: The blist library is not available, so a normal set will be used in place of blist.sortedset for set collection values. You can find the blist library here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/
  "The blist library is not available, so a normal set will "
25% completed - 750 rows inserted.
50% completed - 1500 rows inserted.
75% completed - 2250 rows inserted.
100% completed - 3000 rows inserted.
cass@cass:~/student-files/write-path/exercise-1$

Comment: It's a warning, you can ignore it. Looks like it is working now.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  Sorry, i am newbiew on stackoverflow as well.  How do i mark your answer as CORRECT ?

Comment: I didn't answer, I only commented, but I put the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Install cassandra driver:

```
pip install cassandra-driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem.  When I saw the answers, I realized I probably installed the driver for Python 2.  I tried the following and now it works:

```
pip3 install cassandra-driver
```

The python developers really made it hard on noobs with Python 2 and Python 3 being so incompatible.

Answer (score -4):

You need to install the python driver.

Comment: This page ranks high in Google, yet lacks an answer with specific commands or a even a link. (pip, apt, tarball?  )

Comment: sudo pip install cassandra-driver && sudo pip install cassandra-driver --upgrade && sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev && sudo pip install blist    # assuming you are on Ubuntu.   Also note, the Cassandra driver landscape changes, meaning the best driver to install today might not be the best driver 2 years from now.

Comment: i tried to run above script but terminals says pip command not found..! i am new to python.